# Does the Photos access API in iPhone allow removal of photos from an application?

Tags: ios, api, photos

Our development team is planning a product, and we need to figure out if it's possible to remove photos from Photos library on iOS via our application code. We are basically doing a backup and clean application. Please let me know if this is possible via API's provided by Apple.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html You can delete photos from photos by using Photos.framework but it works for iOS > 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via [Photos.Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/Photos_Framework/) , but it's only available later versions iOS 8.

[Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html) is available at developer's library.

```
    // Delete asset from library
    [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        [PHAssetChangeRequest deleteAssets:@[self.asset]];
    } completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using the Photos framework.
Look into `PHAssetChangeRequest` and the `deleteAssets:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Nope it is not allowed to delete the photos =from app